# How to remove Grid lines except for zero line and border Chartjs?

Tags: chart.js

I want to remove all grid lines in Line ChartJS, except zero line and border.
When disable Y grid lines by field "line: 0", but border line turn off too :(.
Here my code

```
scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          suggestedMin: -maxValue,
          suggestedMax: maxValue,
          fontSize: 15,
          padding: 20,
          callback: value => {
            if (value === 0) {
              return value
            } else if (Number(value).toFixed(1) === maxValue) {
              return value
            } else if (Number(value).toFixed(1) === Number(0 - maxValue).toFixed(1)) {
              return value
            } else {
              return ''
            }
          }
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: true,
          drawBorder: true,
          zeroLineWidth: 2,
          lineWidth: 0,
          drawTicks: false,
          // drawOnChartArea: false,
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
          zeroLineColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
          borderWidth: 5
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          padding: 20
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: true,
          drawBorder: true,
          drawTicks: false,
          drawOnChartArea: false,
          lineWidth: 3,
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
        }
      }]
    },
```

This is result:
[image: Image 1]
And what i want look like:
[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `color` property of `gridline`. If `color` is specified as an array, the first color applies to the first grid line, the second to the second grid line and so on. so define a color for first line and for the rest just define color as transparent so they wont be visible.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
// you need to calculate the step items on axes to make all those color invisible 
var restArr = ['rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)']
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [-12, 19, 3, -5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          suggestedMin: -20,
          suggestedMax: 20,
          fontSize: 15,
          padding: 20,
          callback: value => {
            if (value === 0) {
              return value
            } else if (Number(value).toFixed(1) === 10) {
              return value
            } else if (Number(value).toFixed(1) === Number(0 - 10).toFixed(1)) {
              return value
            } else {
              return ''
            }
          }
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: true,
          drawBorder: true,
          zeroLineWidth: 2,
          lineWidth: 0,
          drawTicks: false,
          drawOnChartArea: true,
          color: ['rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', ...restArr],
          zeroLineColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
          borderWidth: 0
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          padding: 20
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: true,
          drawBorder: true,
          drawTicks: false,
          drawOnChartArea: true,
          lineWidth: 1,
          color: ['rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)', ...restArr],
          zeroLineColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',

        }
      }]
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you bro, and how to remove the line in the top chart?

Comment: I have updated my answer. basically you need to play around gridline colors array to show which line you want to show and which not. this is also useful when you want to show warning/danger levels.